# Linq query select new with List

Tags: c#, list, linq

I'm doing a query which gets back the names of the buyers grouped by the brand of the products they have bought. So far I'm here

```
var query= from p in purchaseRepo.ReadAll()
                  join g in guitarRepo.ReadAll() on p.GuitarId equals g.Id
                  join b in brandRepo.ReadAll() on g.BrandId equals b.Id
                  group p by b.Id into grp
                  select new
                  {
                      grp.Key,
                      grp.SelectMany(t => t.BuyerName)
                  }
```

My problem is that I would like to have a List or an array of the buyer names declared in the select new part's body, but I can't get it to work.
EDIT:
I've given names for the fields is select new it looks like this:

```
select new 
                  {
                     Brand=grp.Key,
                     Buyers=new List<string>()
                      
                  };
```

Now I only need to know how to get the buyer names into the List.
The result should be something like this:
Brand1 --->List of buyer names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pick one:

- Linq offers the [.ToList()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolist) method
- Linq offers the [.ToArray()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup) method
- Be a hero and implement your own method that accepts an *IEnumerable<string>* and returns a list populated with the string elements from that enumerable...

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get it working, thanks everyone for the help!

Here's my query for others struggling:

```
 var asd = from p in purchaseRepo.ReadAll()
                  join g in guitarRepo.ReadAll() on p.GuitarId equals g.Id
                  join b in brandRepo.ReadAll() on g.BrandId equals b.Id
                  group p by b.Name into grp
                  select new
                  {
                      Brand = grp.Key,
                      Buyers = grp.Select(t=>t.BuyerName)

                  };
        var result = asd
            .Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>(
                x.Brand,
                x.Buyers.ToList()
                ));
```

Comment: Please do post self-answer as edit to the question, not a separate post.